# Math Behind the Game "Quoridor"

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, education, article-writing

I'm going to write an article for middle school students to introduce them to the game "[quoridor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoridor)".

[image]

Tha game certainly is interesting, but it will be great to add to the article some serious "math behind the game" stuff.

The problem is, I haven't found any interesting result about the game, neither myself nor on the web. Of course, there are some papers about designing a computer software to play quoridor vs. human etc., but these are not what I'm looking for.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Thinking about it in terms of graph theory would be a start.

Comment: What sort of mathematical result are you expecting?  At first glance from the rules of the game, it doesn't seem to have any connections to anything particularly deep; the game is just a little bit too dynamic to say anything useful about mathematically.  Contrast this against, e.g., Conway's Angels and Devils game, or Piet Hein's Hex, both of which are similar to Quoridor in some senses but with simplicities that make them at some level more 'inherently mathematical'.

Comment: @ Steven Stadnicki Well, I can give two examples of such results: **1.** In the game of "Set", the last three cards always form a set! **2.** In Minesweeper, if you in every empty cell put a mine and empty every cell with mines, then sum of the numbers in the table will not change!

Comment: @ Steven Stadnicki However, I may change my mind and write about on of the games you mentioned. I'm familiar with Hex and I've heard of one of its deep mathematical connections (i.e. with Brouwer fixed point theorem), but I'm just going to read about the other game. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On the wiki page I noticed this appeared:

> Lisa Glendenning (May 2005). *Mastering Quoridor* (B.Sc. thesis). University of New Mexico.

The link to it does not work, but if you can get to it, it probably at least contains references to published work done on the game.

Comment: Thanks. The thesis can be found here: http://www.mendeley.com/profiles/lisa-glendenning. However, it was about algorithms, too.